# Assign SOCKET value by reference to address

Tags: winsock2

Is it possible to pass a `SOCKET` as a pointer to a function that uses `accept` function and assgin the value returned from `accept` by dereferencing the pointer

```
int accepter(SOCKET soc, SOCKET & agent) // soc is the server socket 
{
    agent = accept(soc, NULL,NULL);
    if ( agent == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("accept() failed => [%d]",WSAGetLastError());
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `SOCKET` by reference, not by pointer.  Using a pointer would look like this instead:

```
int accepter(SOCKET soc, SOCKET * agent)
{
    *agent = accept(soc, NULL, NULL);
    if (*agent == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("accept() failed => [%d]", WSAGetLastError());
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But, to answer your question, yes, either way is perfectly possible and legit.